# kafka-console-producer with kerberos throws security-protocol is not a recognized option

Tags: apache-kafka, kerberos, kafka-producer-api, ambari, apache-kafka-security

I have enabled Kerberos from Ambari v2.7.3 and HDP v3.1.0 to all Hadoop services. I have verified HBase authentication using NIFI. I need to test Kafka as well. In Kafka console, I am able to create a topic. But while producing and consuming I am facing an error like below.

```
security-protocol is not a recognized option
```

Below is the Kafka producer command I have tried

```
/usr/hdp/3.1.0.0-78/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list HOSTNAME:6667 --topic test_new_topic --security-protocol SASL_PLAINTEXT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advise would be to add all the properties under a single file (e.g. `client-ssl.properties`) with the following content:

```
security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
```

and finally use `–-producer.config` to pass the property file to the console producer:

```
/usr/hdp/3.1.0.0-78/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh –-broker-list HOSTNAME:6667 –-topic test_new_topic –-producer.config client-ssl.properties
```

If you don't want to use a property file, you can use `--producer-property` to pass the `security.protocol` configuration:

```
/usr/hdp/3.1.0.0-78/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list HOSTNAME:6667 --topic test_new_topic  --producer-property security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `--property` with the property names as following :

```
/usr/hdp/3.1.0.0-78/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list HOSTNAME:6667 --topic test_new_topic  --property security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
```

Comment: I have used above command now I am facing below warnings                                                            [2019-07-10 10:54:56,408] WARN The configuration 'security-protocol' was supplied but isn't a known config. (org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerConfig)
>kakajsj
[2019-07-10 10:55:07,409] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Bootstrap broker 192.168.1.182:6667 (id: -1 rack: null) disconnected (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

Comment: Kafka is up and running and there is no error in the server logs

Comment: what kafka version are you using?

Comment: Kafka version 2.0.0

Comment: I am running single-node Hadoop (HDP v3.1.0) In the same host-only I am trying to publish and consuming the data

Comment: For the above issue, I manually edit in zookeeper client using below command    set /brokers/ids/1001 {"listener_security_protocol_map":{"SASL_PLAINTEXT":"SASL_PLAINTEXT"},"endpoints":["SASL_PLAINTEXT://HOSTNAME:6667"],"jmx_port":-1,"host":HOSTNAME,"timestamp":"1562767293105","port":6667,"version":4}                           but here i am facing this error Authentication is not valid : /brokers/ids/1001

Comment: Now I am trying to consume the data. I am using below command 
                     /usr/hdp/current/kafka-broker/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server HOSTNAME:6667 --topic test --from-beginning --consumer-property security.protocol SASL_PLAINTEXT                     I am getting below error                                       Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.kafka.common.security.auth.SecurityProtocol.